# What is the ideal amount of protein in take daily per body weight?

Tags: nutrition, protein, burn-fat

Is there a way to measure how much protein a person should consume per day based on their body weight?  The objective is to burn fat and maximize metabolism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to build muscle and lose fat, I've heard it's about 1 gram per 1 pound of body weight.

Comment: This is wrong, it would be way too much. What you probably meant to say is 1 gram per pound of **lean** body weight.

Comment: No, My trainers recommended exactly what PMV is saying. I think he's right.

Comment: I heard 1 gram per *desired* body weight.

Comment: I heard 1 gram per pound per lean body weight.